# Banner module not changing on refresh, only on page change

Tags: module, com-banners

The banner module I am using for a single category of banners is not changing the display of the banners when the page is refreshed, they only change when the user navigates to a different page. All of the banners in the category are unpinned and they have no limits on their impressions. I have included a screenshot of the banner module parameters below. Caching is disabled for the module. Any idea why they are not changing upon refreshing the page? Visit http://afca.ab.ca to see the module and how it does not change on refresh.

[image: banner module parameters]

Comment: Maybe You are using some cache, so module is cached for that website, but when You change it You generate another cached, or just use different one.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your description and screenshot you may want to try setting your Randomise variable to "sticky, randomise". You might find it works better if you actually set *all* your banners to sticky in this way since sticky generally causes Joomla to prioritize a single banner and setting them all to sticky levels everything out.

Another thing to check is your banner count in the banner module. Set it to 1. Otherwise you end up with overlapping banners with the same one on top every page refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Keep this point when you creating the banner:
1.select categories →create new category.
2. go to the components → banners → select the client → create a new client.
3.now goto banners → give the name for the banner → select image for the banner → specify height and width.
4.go to banner detail tab select the client name.
5.Then create the module for the Banner extensions → modules → new → Banners → give the name for the banner and select the client and category.
6.In randomize drop down box → select pinned,randomized.
Choose the position for the banner.
7.do the 3 rd step for creating another banners and press save and close.
Now visit the site refresh the page. now your banner get rotated .

Comment: This does not offer any assistance with my issue. The banners have been created and each has it's own client, but they are all part of one category called "external". The module is set to display four banners from the "external" category. No client has been set. The module is successfully displaying the banners, it is just not rotating on page refresh. They are only changing when the page is changed using the navigation or other links.

Comment: Though the process outlined here *should* work, this doesn't directly answer the question.